# / is adding at the beginning of URL

Tags: php, html, anchor

I was making a navbar in which I have to add internal hyperlinks. When I am adding the dynamic base URL, my code is adding a / (slash) at the beginning of the URL.

I am adding the anchor tag like that in my PHP file.

```html
<a href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>#abc">ABC</a>
```

where

```php
$base_url = "http://localhost/foo/foo";
```

When I am inspecting the hyperlink through dev tools, this is shown in the anchor tag.

```html
<a href="/http://localhost/foo/foo/#abc">ABC</a>
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: `echo base_url;` should give you an error with "undefined constant". If you just lost the `$` in transit and it's in your actual code, then what you get does not follow from the code you've shown.

Comment: @MarkusAO Yes, I added that in my code, forgot to add in the question

Comment: Looks like it's a typo somewhere in the code (in the markup). It's more important to check that server sends proper code to the browser (you may check this via Right Mouse Button click > Show page's code. Does this project contain any javascript code? It may also affect the links under the hood

Comment: Based on the code you shared here, what you say can not happen. In fact, by copying and pasting your code in any PHP file the slashes are not added. Which means that either: 1. you didn't post the whole code here; 2. when you posted the code here you changed it; 3. there's other JS code involved. Share your whole relevant real code if you want to truly debug this

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url.'#abc'">ABC</a>
```

Comment: This method isn't working, giving the same results

Comment: Try to add slash at the end #abc/